# Javascript concat and prefix or rename props

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays that I am concatinating.
However each of these arrays has same property name I want to leave by adding prefix to each.

Array A(`aData`) looks like

```
[
  {
   id: 1,
   title: `title`
   code: '34x'
  },
  ...
]
```

Array B(`bData`) looke like:

```
[
  {
   id: 1
   prop: 3,
   otherporp: `prop`
   code: 'hi67'
   },
   ...
]
```

In order to combine the arrays I am doing `concat` and `reduce` to get only matching `id's`

```
const data: any = aData.concat(bData).reduce((acc, x) => {
          acc[x.id] = Object.assign(acc[x.id] || {}, x);
          return acc;
        }, {});
        return Object.values(data);
```

But the issue is that my `bData` `code` props getting lost.

Is there any way I can rename the `code` from `aData` to say `aCode` and the `code` from `bData` to `bCode` ?

Comment: confues about your code `const data: any = ` and don't know what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new array from both of your array with updated key value `aCode` and `bCode` instead of `code` key. Then concat both of these arrays and merge them on the `id` key.

```js
const arrA = [{ id: 1, title: `title`, code: '34x' }],
      arrB = [{ id: 1, prop: 3, otherporp: `prop`, code: 'hi67'}];
const newArrA = arrA.map(({code, ...rest}) => ({...rest, aCode : code}));
const newArrB = arrB.map(({code, ...rest}) => ({...rest, bCode : code}))
      
const merged = Object.values([].concat(newArrA, newArrB).reduce((r,o) => {
        r[o.id] = r[o.id] || Object.assign({},o);
        Object.assign(r[o.id], o);
        return r;
      }, {}));
console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arrA = [{
        id: 1,
        title: `title`,
        code: '34x'
    }],
    arrB = [{
        id: 1,
        prop: 3,
        otherporp: `prop`,
        code: 'hi67'
    }];
let newArrA = arrA.map(({
    code,
    ...rest
}) => ({ ...rest,
    aCode: code
}));
const newArrB = arrB.map(({
    code,
    ...rest
}) => ({ ...rest,
    bCode: code
}));

result = newArrA.map(function(v) {
    var ret;
    $.each(newArrB, function(k, v2) {
        if (v2.id === v.id) {
            ret = $.extend({}, v2, v);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return ret;
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```